# jinja2 printing key from dict_keys

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, jinja2

I am using jinja template to print the key of a dictionary.

here is the code:

```
from jinja2 import Template
import json

data = '''
hello {{Names}}
   Heading is {{ Names.keys() }}
'''

schema = '''
{
   "Names" : [
     "Name1",
     "Name2",
     "Name3"
 ]
}
'''

k = json.loads(schema)

tm = Template(data)
jdata = tm.render(Names=k)
print(jdata)
```

with this it is printing template as `dict_keys`, see output below:

```
hello {'Names': ['Name1', 'Name2', 'Name3']}
   Heading is dict_keys(['Names'])
```

so, I think `dict_keys` is of type `set` which doesn't support indexing and also i am not able to use `list` method (as normally used in python) to convert it to list and then use indexing.

I want to print it as a string, expected output:

```
hello {'Names': ['Name1', 'Name2', 'Name3']}
       Heading is Names  # see the Names, it is string
```

Comment: What is Names has multiples keys ?

Comment: What result do you expect? It's not completely clear to me what's your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `",".join()` for example, to print the keys

```
data = '''
hello {{Names}}
   Heading is {{ ",".join(Names.keys()) }}
'''
```

That gives

```py
from jinja2 import Template

data = '''
hello {{Names}}
   Heading is {{ ",".join(Names.keys()) }}
'''
k = {'Names': ['Name1', 'Name2', 'Name3'], 'other_key': 5}
tm = Template(data)
jdata = tm.render(Names=k)
print(jdata)
```

```
hello {'Names': ['Name1', 'Name2', 'Name3'], 'other_key': 5}
   Heading is Names,other_key
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but yes i am worried about other keys, thats why looking for indexing. if there is any builtin way in jinja template to convert set to list as normally we have in python that may be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the following result:

```
hello {'Names': ['Name1', 'Name2', 'Name3']}
   Heading is ['Name1', 'Name2', 'Name3']
```

You can just access the `Names` content of your array from within your Jinja template:

```
data = '''
hello {{Names}}
   Heading is {{ Names["Names"] }}
'''
```

---

If you don't want the brackets:

```
hello {'Names': ['Name1', 'Name2', 'Name3']}
   Heading is Name1, Name2, Name3
```

Just join the list items with a delimiter e.g. `", "`:

```
data = '''
hello {{Names}}
   Heading is {{ ", ".join(Names["Names"]) }}
'''
```

Comment: but i need to print 'Names' (the top level key) from my schema in the heading line, see my expected output and it may be the case that schema can contain multiple keys, so indexing is required.

Comment: In that case, I think @azro already gave you the answer.

Comment: yes, but with @azro answer also it is join function, which will break with multiple keys. so looking for indexing.

Comment: Could you provide a sample schema with multiple keys? Unfortunately, I'm not sure if I understand it correctly :)